# How to get the data from a Rowmapper on a pieChart?

Tags: java, primefaces, pie-chart

```
public FewosByRegion mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowInt) throws SQLException
{
    FewosByRegion fewosByRegion = new FewosByRegion();
    fewosByRegion.setGenferseegebiet(rs.getString(1));
    fewosByRegion.setTotalRecordsG(rs.getInt(2));
    return fewosByRegion;
}

public PieChartModel getPieModel()
{
    this.pieModel.getData().put(FewosByRegion.setGenferseegebiet(null));
    this.pieModel.getData().put("RegionName", 010);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get Data from a Database on a pieModel?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43204956/how-to-get-data-from-a-database-on-a-piemodel)

Comment: Please, don't create duplicates. Try to improve your other question.

Comment: ok thnks its not exactly duplicate

Comment: Then, please improve both questions